# Pytorch mixed precision causing discriminator loss to go to NaN in WGAN-GP

Tags: python, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I'm going to preface this by saying I don't have a lot of experience with neural networks - less so with Pytorch in general. I'm trying to implement mixed precision in a WGAN-GP implementation (not mine) so that I can save GPU memory and train a bit faster.

I got the code from [here](https://github.com/aladdinpersson/Machine-Learning-Collection/tree/master/ML/Pytorch/GANs/4.%20WGAN-GP), but I made my own Generator/Discriminator models, which I will put at the bottom.

The training loop looks as follows:

```py
scaler1 = torch.cuda.amp.GradScaler()
scaler2 = torch.cuda.amp.GradScaler()

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    # Target labels not needed! <3 unsupervised
    for batch_idx, (real, _) in enumerate(loader):
        real = real.to(device)
        cur_batch_size = real.shape[0]

        with torch.cuda.amp.autocast():
            noise = torch.randn(cur_batch_size, LATENT_SIZE, 1, 1).to(device)
            fake = gen(noise)
            critic_real = critic(real).reshape(-1)
            critic_fake = critic(fake).reshape(-1)
            gp = gradient_penalty(critic, real, fake, device=device, scaler = scaler1)
            loss_critic = (
                -(torch.mean(critic_real) - torch.mean(critic_fake)) + LAMBDA_GP * gp
            )
        critic.zero_grad()
        #loss_critic.backward(retain_graph=True)
        #opt_critic.step()
        scaler1.scale(loss_critic).backward(retain_graph = True)
        scaler1.unscale_(opt_critic)
        scaler1.step(opt_critic)

        # Train Generator: max E[critic(gen_fake)] <-> min -E[critic(gen_fake)]

        with torch.cuda.amp.autocast():
            gen_fake = critic(fake).reshape(-1)
            loss_gen = -torch.mean(gen_fake)

        
        gen.zero_grad()
        #loss_gen.backward()
        #opt_gen.step()

        scaler2.scale(loss_gen).backward(retain_graph = True)
        scaler2.unscale_(opt_gen)
        scaler2.step(opt_gen)

        scaler1.update()
        scaler2.update()
```

And the gradient penalty function:

```py
def gradient_penalty(critic, real, fake, device="cpu", scaler = None):
    BATCH_SIZE, C, H, W = real.shape
    alpha = torch.rand((BATCH_SIZE, 1, 1, 1)).repeat(1, C, H, W).to(device)
    interpolated_images = real * alpha + fake * (1 - alpha)

    # Calculate critic scores
    mixed_scores = critic(interpolated_images)

    # Take the gradient of the scores with respect to the images
    gradient = torch.autograd.grad(
        inputs=interpolated_images,
        outputs=mixed_scores if scaler is None else scaler.scale(mixed_scores),
        grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(mixed_scores),
        create_graph=True,
        retain_graph=True,
    )[0]
    
    gradient = gradient / scaler.get_scale() if scaler is not None else gradient
    
    gradient = gradient.view(gradient.shape[0], -1)
    gradient_norm = gradient.norm(2, dim=1)
    gradient_penalty = torch.mean((gradient_norm - 1) ** 2)
    return gradient_penalty
```

I've tested this without mixed precision, and it seems to do well enough, but after I tried to implement mixed precision, the discriminator loss becomes NaN after a few batches. The generator loss appears to be normal (however it starts out negative, which I'm not sure is OK but it becomes positive later when not using mixed precision).

The following are my Generator and Discriminator models:

```py
class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, targetSize, channels, features, latentSize):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        
        mult = int(np.log(targetSize)/np.log(2) - 3)
        startFactor = 2**mult
        
        self.network = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(latentSize, features * startFactor, 4, 1, 0, bias = False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(features * startFactor),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
            *sum([self.__block(int(features * startFactor / (2**i)), int(features * startFactor / (2**(i+1)))) for i in range(mult)], []),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(features, channels, 4, 2, 1, bias = False),
            nn.Tanh(),
            )

    def __block(self, in_features, out_features):
        layers = [nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_features, out_features, 4, 2, 1, bias = False)]
        layers.append(nn.BatchNorm2d(out_features))
        layers.append(nn.LeakyReLU(0.2))
        return layers

    def forward(self, inp):
        return self.network(inp)
    
class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, targetSize, channels, features):
        super(Discriminator, self).__init__()
        
        mult = int(np.log(targetSize)/np.log(2) - 3)
        startFactor = 2**mult

        self.network = nn.Sequential(

            nn.Conv2d(channels, features, 4, 2, 1, bias = False),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
            *sum([self.__block(int(features * (2**i)), int(features * (2**(i+1)))) for i in range(mult)],[]),
            nn.Conv2d(features * startFactor, 1, 4, 2, 0, bias = False),
            )

    def __block(self, in_features, out_features):
        layers = [nn.Conv2d(in_features, out_features, 4, 2, 1, bias = False)]
        layers.append(nn.InstanceNorm2d(out_features, affine=True))
        layers.append(nn.LeakyReLU(0.2))
        return layers

    def forward(self, inp):
        return self.network(inp)
```

[image: FP16]

[image: FP32]

NOTE: The FP16 chart ends on step ~140 because it becomes NaN from that point onwards.

I've also created pastebins for the raw data: [FP32](https://pastebin.com/a2K2JutH) and [FP16](https://pastebin.com/3Pykf1Rr)

Comment: is your discriminator loss diverging? could you share the loss output

Comment: I've updated the question with the relevant loss plots, as well as links to the raw data (Batch size of 32, learning rate of 1e-4).

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this for a week and am not sure whether I've fully solved it yet, but at least it's running stable now.

Move the gradient_penalty() function outside of `with autocast`. Only the normalization portion should be within the `with autocast`. These gradients should be manually scaled.

Here is an example from pytorch: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/amp_examples.html#gradient-penalty

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same problem, can you show me your training logs

Comment: @CuCaRot: Sorry I don't have them. But the article I linked to really solved it. I didn't run into the problem anymore.

Comment: I modified the code as the documents (scale the gradient manually) but the penalty is still dynamic increasing after a few steps. Besides that, since you succeed in training gans, can you tell me what is the normal range of loss D and loss G (penalty is in range (15-70 as you said on Pytorch forum))

Comment: With WGAN-GP I had a G penalty between 10 and 50. The D penalty was below 10. But I think this differs greatly per project. Some combinations of hyperparameters had a higher loss, but better results. At first the loss will go crazy, so wait until it stabilizes and then use the general trend to determine whether the loss is improving. The loss is likely not going to 0 as ,according to this article, blurry images can outperform realistic ones based on the Wasserstein loss: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.01678.pdf. Have at least a look at the images.